# SUM From_value and To_value between each Complete in the class column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to sum the from_value and to_value between each occurrence of "COMPLETE" in the `class` column.

| ID | Class | User ID | Location | From_value | To_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | COMPLETE | 3075 | 1-C |  |  |
| 3 | ADJUST | 3075 | 1-C | 5 | 7 |
| 4 | ADD | L146 | 2-D | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | COMPLETE | L151 | 5-B |  |  |
| 6 | MATCH | L151 | 5-B | 8 | 6 |
| 7 | COMPLETE | L102 | 3-C |  |  |
| 8 | MATCH | L102 | 3-C | 1 | 1 |
| 9 | MATCH | L102 | 3-C | 2 | 1 |
| 12 | MATCH | L102 | 3-C | 1 | 2 |
| 13 | MATCH | L102 | 3-C | 1 | 1 |
| 14 | MATCH | L102 | 3-C | 3 | 1 |
| 15 | MATCH | L102 | 3-C | 1 | 1 |
| 16 | COMPLETE | L151 | 5-C |  |  |
| 17 | MATCH | L151 | 5-C | 6 | 5 |
| 18 | COMPLETE | L193 | 4-B |  |  |
| 19 | ADJUST | L193 | 4-B | 0 | 1 |
| 20 | ADJUST | L193 | 4-B | 0 | 1 |
| 21 | MATCH | L193 | 4-B | 1 | 1 |
| 22 | MATCH | L193 | 4-B | 1 | 1 |
| 23 | MATCH | L193 | 4-B | 1 | 1 |
| 24 | MATCH | L193 | 4-B | 1 | 1 |
| 25 | MATCH | L193 | 4-B | 1 | 1 |
| 26 | MATCH | L193 | 4-B | 1 | 1 |
| 27 | MATCH | L193 | 4-B | 1 | 1 |
| 28 | MATCH | L193 | 4-B | 1 | 1 |

For example for this part:

| ID | Class | User ID | Location | From_value | To_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | COMPLETE | L102 | 3-C |  |  |
| 8 | MATCH | L102 | 3-C | 1 | 1 |
| 9 | MATCH | L102 | 3-C | 2 | 1 |
| 12 | MATCH | L102 | 3-C | 1 | 2 |
| 13 | MATCH | L102 | 3-C | 1 | 1 |
| 14 | MATCH | L102 | 3-C | 3 | 1 |
| 15 | MATCH | L102 | 3-C | 1 | 1 |
| 16 | COMPLETE | L151 | 5-C |  |  |

should total up into this:

| ID | Class | User ID | Location | From_value | To_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | COMPLETE | L102 | 3-C | 9 | 7 |

I can't simply group by location as the same location could appear multiple times, I need to total the from and to value between each occurrence of "complete" in the class column.

What I have tried to do so far is to lag the ID of each occurrence of "COMPLETE" in the class column. I then have a list of IDs at which "complete" occurs in the class column, I now need to use this ID list as a condition to sum between. I am not sure how to do this part.

This is my query:

```
with obj1 as 
(
    select 
        class, user_id, location, from_value, to_value, id, 
        id1 = lag (id, 1) over (order by id)
    from 
        table_0 
    where 
        class = 'COMPLETE' 
)
select 
    loc.user_id, loc.location, 
    sum(cast(loc.from_value as int)) as F_value, 
    sum(cast(loc.to_value as int)) as T_value, 
    loc.ID
from
    table_0 loc
left join 
    obj1 on loc.user_id = obj1.user_id 
         and loc.location = obj1.location
         and isnumeric(loc.from_value) = 1 
         and isnumeric(loc.to_value) = 1
group by 
    loc.user_id, loc.location, loc.ID
```

I'm expected to have a table that looks like this at the end;

| ID | Class | User ID | Location | From_value | To_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | COMPLETE | 3075 | 1-C | 5 | 7 |
| 5 | COMPLETE | L151 | 5-B | 8 | 6 |
| 7 | COMPLETE | L102 | 3-C | 9 | 7 |
| 16 | COMPLETE | L151 | 5-C | 6 | 5 |
| 18 | COMPLETE | L193 | 4-B | 8 | 10 |

Comment: Explaining the expected results goes a long way to helping us understand the problem; don't just expect us the *guess* what the expected results show.

Comment: I have tried my best to do this, thank you for your comment

Answer (score 2):

Waiting for your detailed expected results as Dale told you, you could use following query (remember: in sql I suggest to keep things as simple as possibile) and try to give sample data as follow:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
   ID         INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
  ,Class      VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL
  ,User_ID    VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL
  ,Location   VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL
  ,From_value INTEGER 
  ,To_value   INTEGER 
);
INSERT INTO mytable(ID,Class,User_ID,Location,From_value,To_value) VALUES (2,'COMPLETE','3075','1-C',NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO mytable(ID,Class,User_ID,Location,From_value,To_value) VALUES (3,'ADJUST','3075','1-C',5,7);
INSERT INTO mytable(ID,Class,User_ID,Location,From_value,To_value) VALUES (4,'ADD','L146','2-D',0,0);
INSERT INTO mytable(ID,Class,User_ID,Location,From_value,To_value) VALUES (5,'COMPLETE','L151','5-B',NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO mytable(ID,Class,User_ID,Location,From_value,To_value) VALUES (6,'MATCH','L151','5-B',8,6);
INSERT INTO mytable(ID,Class,User_ID,Location,From_value,To_value) VALUES (7,'COMPLETE','L102','3-C',NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO mytable(ID,Class,User_ID,Location,From_value,To_value) VALUES (8,'MATCH','L102','3-C',1,1);
INSERT INTO mytable(ID,Class,User_ID,Location,From_value,To_value) VALUES (9,'MATCH','L102','3-C',2,1);
INSERT INTO mytable(ID,Class,User_ID,Location,From_value,To_value) VALUES (12,'MATCH','L102','3-C',1,2);
INSERT INTO mytable(ID,Class,User_ID,Location,From_value,To_value) VALUES (13,'MATCH','L102','3-C',1,1);
INSERT INTO mytable(ID,Class,User_ID,Location,From_value,To_value) VALUES (14,'MATCH','L102','3-C',3,1);
INSERT INTO mytable(ID,Class,User_ID,Location,From_value,To_value) VALUES (15,'MATCH','L102','3-C',1,1);
INSERT INTO mytable(ID,Class,User_ID,Location,From_value,To_value) VALUES (16,'COMPLETE','L151','5-C',NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO mytable(ID,Class,User_ID,Location,From_value,To_value) VALUES (17,'MATCH','L151','5-C',6,5);
INSERT INTO mytable(ID,Class,User_ID,Location,From_value,To_value) VALUES (18,'COMPLETE','L193','4-B',NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO mytable(ID,Class,User_ID,Location,From_value,To_value) VALUES (19,'ADJUST','L193','4-B',0,1);
INSERT INTO mytable(ID,Class,User_ID,Location,From_value,To_value) VALUES (20,'ADJUST','L193','4-B',0,1);
INSERT INTO mytable(ID,Class,User_ID,Location,From_value,To_value) VALUES (21,'MATCH','L193','4-B',1,1);
INSERT INTO mytable(ID,Class,User_ID,Location,From_value,To_value) VALUES (22,'MATCH','L193','4-B',1,1);
INSERT INTO mytable(ID,Class,User_ID,Location,From_value,To_value) VALUES (23,'MATCH','L193','4-B',1,1);
INSERT INTO mytable(ID,Class,User_ID,Location,From_value,To_value) VALUES (24,'MATCH','L193','4-B',1,1);
INSERT INTO mytable(ID,Class,User_ID,Location,From_value,To_value) VALUES (25,'MATCH','L193','4-B',1,1);
INSERT INTO mytable(ID,Class,User_ID,Location,From_value,To_value) VALUES (26,'MATCH','L193','4-B',1,1);
INSERT INTO mytable(ID,Class,User_ID,Location,From_value,To_value) VALUES (27,'MATCH','L193','4-B',1,1);
INSERT INTO mytable(ID,Class,User_ID,Location,From_value,To_value) VALUES (28,'MATCH','L193','4-B',1,1);
```

The first part of the FROM extracts Id, User_Id and Location with "COMPLETE".  In the LEFT JOIN, you use User_id and Location to extract values to SUM.

```
SELECT A.id
  , A.User_ID
  , A.Location
  , SUM(FROM_Value) AS From_Value
  , SUM(TO_Value) AS TO_Value
FROM (SELECT id, User_ID, Location FROM mytable WHERE CLASS='COMPLETE')  A
LEFT JOIN mytable B ON A.User_ID= B.User_ID AND A.Location=B.Location AND B.CLASS<>'COMPLETE'
GROUP BY A.id, A.User_ID, B.Location 
ORDER BY A.Id, A.User_ID
```

Output:

```
+----+---------+----------+------------+----------+
| id | User_ID | Location | From_Value | TO_Value |
+----+---------+----------+------------+----------+
|  2 | 3075    | 1-C      |          5 |        7 |
|  5 | L151    | 5-B      |          8 |        6 |
|  7 | L102    | 3-C      |          9 |        7 |
| 16 | L151    | 5-C      |          6 |        5 |
| 18 | L193    | 4-B      |          8 |       10 |
+----+---------+----------+------------+----------+
```

----- added----

If, for some reasons that you did not explain, you want "to limit" extraction between two "complete" events, I think following query could help you as starting point:

```
SELECT A.ID, A.USER_ID, A.LOCATION
    , SUM(B.FROM_VALUE ) AS F_VALUE
    , SUM(B.TO_VALUE ) AS T_VALUE
FROM  (SELECT USER_ID
            , LOCATION  
            , ID
            , LEAD (ID, 1) OVER (ORDER BY ID ) AS ID_NEXT
    FROM   MYTABLE 
    WHERE  CLASS = 'COMPLETE' ) A
LEFT JOIN MYTABLE B  ON A.USER_ID = B.USER_ID 
                        AND A.LOCATION = B.LOCATION
                        AND  B.ID>A.ID 
                        AND B.ID <COALESCE(A.ID_NEXT,9999999)
GROUP BY  A.ID, A.USER_ID, A.LOCATION
```

(with data you published, this query gives same results as my first query).

Comment: Your assumption in the added code is correct, we do need to limit the summing between the two complete events.

There is also one other issue I missed that I can't figure out, the "from_value" and "to_value" columns are varchar columns that are sometimes numbers and sometimes words. I have tried to edit your code and check for this but it is throwing errors.

Comment: 1) if a given answer is helping you, you shoud vote it first of all.
2) if you have other question, one can be glad to help you again, but you should show what are you doing and describe as exactly as possibile your tries (in stack overflow you can find people willing to help you, but they do not write code for you: show your efforts please).

Comment: @elsa you provide a good solution and that s way i vote your ansewer